# Поделиться файлом SharedPreferences на API 24+

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, android-intent, uri

По пути *data/data/com.app.app/shared_prefs/* находятся файлы, которые пользователь должен отправлять, например, в облако.

Такая запись:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(((File) it.next()));
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

на API 24+ не работает. Необходимо использовать:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.app.app.provider", ((File) it.next()));
```

Вот только крашится с ошибкой:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find
>   configured root that contains
>   /data/data/com.app.app/shared_prefs/file.xml

Сделал всё как надо по туториалу из документации по провайдеру - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html. Но если верить этим подсказкам:

> The root path of this subdirectory is the same as the value returned
>   by getCacheDir().

Ни один из вариантов мне не подходит.

```
getFilesDir: /data/user/0/com.app.app/files
getCacheDir: /data/user/0/com.app.app/cache
getExternalStorageDirectory: /storage/emulated/0
getExternalFilesDir: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.app/files
getExternalCacheDir: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.app/cache
```

Т.к. мои файлы находятся в папке SharedPreferences. Есть ли вариант таки поделиться ими, кроме как копирования их в одну из папок выше и последующего удаления?

Манифест:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.app.app.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:ignore="InnerclassSeparator">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml. Пробовал всевозможные разные варианты, но безрезультатно. Сейчас там так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path path="data/data/com.app.app/shared_prefs/" name="shared_prefs" />
    <external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>
```

Comment: попробуйте прочитать через каталог: `prefsDir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs");`

Comment: В документации не упоминается тег `root-path` и, наверное, не зря - так что пробуйте сами  `<root-path path="data/data/com.app.app/shared_prefs/" name="shared_prefs" />`. Хотя абсолютный путь к папке приложения может отличаться на разных API и аппаратах и это дополнительный геморрой.